# axios request don't work inside .forEach() nor inside .map()

Tags: reactjs, axios

i'm trying to create delete button that delete a group of objects instead of one object, but the axios request don't work inside the forEach loop.

```
function handleClick(e) {
            cont GetByName = axios.get('my/api/link').filter(i => i.mylist === `${name}`)
            GetByName.forEach(i => axios.delete('my/api/link'+i.id))
      }
```

#### Please Note: I didn't add `.then(res=>consolse.log(res)` just to make it make it brief.

#### Also note: that using `console.log` instead of `axios.delete` is working very fine.

## Maybe I can explain my problem in another approach

```
const [Id,setId] = useState(null)
function handleClick(e) {
            cont GetByName = axios.get('my/api/link').filter(i => i.mylist === `${name}`)
            GetByName.forEach(i => setId(i.id))
            console.log(Id)
      }
```

this `console.log` return null

Comment: `axios.get()` is **async** so you need to **await** to use the response array, if that's an array.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: I tried `GetByName.forEach(async (i )=> await axios.delete('my/api/link'+i.id)) ` but didn't work as well.

Comment: You may want to create a "delete many" endpoint on your server vs looping an unknown amount of id's and deleting each one individually.

Comment: Maybe I can explain my problem in another approach 

```
const [Id,setId] = useState(null)
function handleClick(e) {
            cont GetByName = axios.get('my/api/link').filter(i => i.mylist === `${name}`)
            GetByName.forEach(i => setId(i.id))
            console.log(id)
      }
```
this `console.log` return null for me

Answer (score 0):

Solved using `setTimeout(() => {}, 0))`

```
function handleClick(e) {
            cont GetByName = axios.get('my/api/link').filter(i => i.mylist === `${name}`)
            GetByName.forEach(i => {
                setTimeout(() => {
                axios.delete('my/api/link'+i.id)  
            }, 0))
})
      }
```